# HTML/CSS - Centering ul in block-element vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

**The HTML**

```
<nav class="cf">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**THE CSS**

```
.cf:before, .cf:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
}

nav {
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  font-size: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

nav li {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline;
}

nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 33px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

**The Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/M9Sdd/

**The Question**
How do I center the `ul` (red background) vertically inside the `nav` (grey background)?

Comment: If I had a nickel for every 'vertically-center' css question that was posted on SO, I'd have a $h1tload of nickels.

Comment: is your logo fixed height? just set margin-top

Comment: @Ben No, too bad. The layout has to be made responsive later on.

Comment: @AlienWebguy cf. Related column on the right hand side of this question :)

Comment: @Sven Just adjust the margin-top in your responsive overrides

Comment: @AlienWebguy If I had a nickel for every 'vertically-center' problem I can't solve by myself, I'd have a $h1tload of nickels ;-)

Comment: @Ben Well, actually it works, but still a "generic" solution would be better I guess as this way, the `margin-top` value is a "magic number". See this link for what I mean: http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/

Comment: if I had a nickel every time someone gets a free nickel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use this without adding other elements:

```
nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

*note: I can only test the code in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/RfF7t/

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around the ul make it table-cell and vertical align middle.

http://jsbin.com/otucom/4/edit

Comment: I really like the idea, but in my case it's not working, I don't know why. See http://jsfiddle.net/4wXVY/